# how to add adjacent values in Array[Double]

Tags: scala

```
val values = Array[Double].sliding(2).map(x => x.reduce(_ + _) / 2)
```

This works successfully. But if that array contains 10000 or more values, it take times to get the values. Is there a faster method to find the adjacent values?

Comment: What's the `/ 2`? Do you want the average of adjacent elements? Also why call reduce when there's only two elements to add? `Just do (x(0) + x(1))/2` Or `x.sum/2`

Comment: yes i want to find the average also

Comment: Does the result have to be an array? Or can it be a List or or Vector or something?

Comment: If you are optimizing for performance you might consider bit shifting instead of dividing `Array[Double].sliding(2).map(_.sum >> 1)`

Comment: @SaschaKolberg, I will be amazed if the compiler and/or the JVM doesn't do that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be faster:

`val values = (for(i <- 0 until array.length - 1) yield ((array(i) + array(i + 1)) / 2)).toArray`

Answer (score 1):

Going low-level:

```
var i = 0
val valuesLength = array.length - 1
val values = new Array[Double](valuesLength)
while (i < valuesLength) {
  values(i) = (array(i) + array(i + 1)) / 2
  i += 1
}
```

Of course, you should only do this if this is actually a bottleneck in your program.